# Propel Row Lock Batch Update Problem

Tags: propel

I am using [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org) as my ORM.

I need to do a batch update to a table with the following fields:

```
ID
Company
Assigned
```

The update will take in an array of `Company` and set the `Assigne`d field to `1`.

The issue is there might be 2 batch updates that occur at the same time. So when that happens, I will have to accept one update, and reject another. Is there anyway to lock the table for one batch update? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://markmail.org/message/4g6l6jmji6t66sry

Comment: @Sam, I am quite skeptical about the solution proposed in your link; it seems that the solution proposed is to add a field and check whether the field is occupied. However, the underlying field in the database is not touched at all. Meaning if the user instantiate a new object in a different call, the field is still false. It doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found.

Instead of locking it, a better way is to use the following equivalent query when doing the batch update

```
update table 
set Assigned=2
where Assigned=1
and Company in {company1, company2}
```

Now, if the number of rows returned is not the same as the number of `Company` selected, then the whole operation should be [rolled back](http://propel.phpdb.org/docs/api/1.3/runtime/propel-util/PropelPDO.html#methodrollback).